# Through-wall AC troubleshooting

Tags: air-conditioning, maintenance

The AC produces cool air for a short period and then ceases to produces cold air after 10-20 minutes.   It will repeat this cycle if turned off for ~1.5 hours

- What can be concluded from the observations above (freon quantity, compressor status)

This AC is an older Fedders A1A10W7: these were designed to be serviced vs today's disposable ACs.   Before dropping $1K on a new AC.  I would think it make sense to determine if there is a simple check or repair will extend the service life.   If it makes any difference, the 3rd story AC faces a busy avenue in urban city

- Is there a simple diagnostic or corrective (maintenance?) action I can perform before replacing the unit?

Suggestions with links to procedures / videos are always appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First check to make sure that your coils are all clean.  Make sure the condenser fan is running.  Check temperature of condenser coil.  It should be hot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the system is low on charge and is icing up. The clue is that I'd has to be turned off for 1.5 hours and will work again. If there is a service port this should be a simple recharge only takes a few minutes. Even if it was not made with a service port they can be added I Cary some that work with 3 different pipe sizes and they cost under 10$. The only thing that may be cost prohibitive is if the unit runs on r12 or r22 but most small units take less than a pound so you may be able to get in running for 150$ or so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean its a "window unit".
I agree to clean it up thoroughly. 
since it gives cold air at begging, I assume the freon and mechanical issues are not the problem.
Recently, I opened 3 window ac, the (external side) evaporator was 90% clogged.
you may need to use compressed air to blow first then, spray degreaser, vacuum, brushing, etc.
One unit show similar simptom - it's freezing up. due to condensed water was not draining out. they got ice dam and causing overheat. I adjusted level and use towel paper to syphon the water out of the base (tray). hope this help if you are handy.